# Return only top level fields in elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document that has nested fields. Example:

```
    "mappings": {
        "blogpost": {
          "properties": {
            "title": { "type": "text"  },
            "body":  { "type": "text"  },
            "comments": {
              "type": "nested", 
              "properties": {
                "name":    { "type": "text"  },
                "comment": { "type": "text"  },
                "age":     { "type": "short"   },
                "stars":   { "type": "short"   },
                "date":    { "type": "date"    }
              }
            }
          }
        }
  }
}
```

Can the query be modified so that the response only contains non-nested fields?

In this example, the response would only contain `body` and `title`.

Using `_source` you can exclude/include fields

```
GET /blogpost/_search
{
    "_source":{
        "excludes":["comments"]
    }
}
```

But you have to explicitly put the field names inside exclude, I'm searching for a way to exclude all nested fields without knowing their field name

Comment: Can you show the query you're sending now?

Comment: yes, I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that but in a static way, which means you entered the field(s) name using [excludes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-request-source-filtering.html) keyword, like:

```
GET your_index/_search
{
    "_source": {
        "excludes": "comments"  
    },
    "query": {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
```

`excludes` can take an `array` of strings; not just one string.

Comment: yes, I’ve been searching if there is something like “excludes”:”nested” or something that, to exclude everything except the top level fields without having to explicitly include all the nested fields in “exclude”